# Element is not clickable in selenium java (chrome driver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I am getting exceptions, when i am trying to click on Edit Criteria. Please someone can help me as

```
public void selectCriteriaFromWorklistsOptions() {
        waitABit(Constants.medium);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                WebElement dropDown = getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(div.nav-menu__group > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)));
                dropDown.click();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug((e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I tried this also -

```
 WebElement element = waitForCondition().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Edit criteria')])")));
 element.click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wait for this element to become clickable.
And try using the following `css selector`:

```
.bttn-menu"
```

Or:

```
.nav-menu_bttn>.bttn-menu
```

**Try 2**:

```
button[bss-bttn-menu]
```

**Try 3**:
It should look like this in Java:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(.nav-menu_bttn>button[bss-bttn-menu]")));
```

Check the amount of underscores _ by yourself. Probably there are two of them.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is helpful

Comment: I tried with both XPath. It is not working

Comment: It is not xpath, it's css

Comment: Check out try 2

Comment: Convert it to Java.

Comment: OK, I'll remove python code, leave only locator

Comment: I checked this browser (button[bss-bttn-menu]) , I am getting 61 result

Comment: Can you share html code of the site? Is it public?

Comment: It is not public. However i have the screenshot

Comment: Check option 3.